# Contextual filter does not work with page with wildcard path

Tags: views

I'm stuck on something. I have a view with a path with a wildcard "/the-register/%". I would like to use the contextual filter, to filter on taxonomy term id or name. But when i add a contextual filter "Taxonomyterm-ID" with a fixed value 1, it's showing up nice in the preview, but when i go to the page it self it does'n show anything?

I'm using drupal 8.7.8. It also occures in drupal 8.7.6.

steps to reproduce:

- create a "view" with a page set it on a content with taxonomy field
- set the path to "/the-register/%"
- create a "Relationship" "Taxonomy term" with "Vocabularies" on the Taxonomy name and enable "Require this relationship"
- create a "Contextual filter" on "Taxonomy term: Term ID", set "Relationship" on the previous created relation and "Provide default value" on "Fixed" and in the "Fixed value" "1" (the taxonomy term id)
- save the view
- press "Update preview"

Now you see some results in the preview, but if you go to "/the-register/asdfsdfs" nothing is shown

Comment: Did you go to `/the-register/1` ?

Comment: what is the page URL that you said it's not working?

Comment: The real problem is, that i have two views one "/the-register", with a overview of taxonomy terms, and the second "/the-register/%" that shows all the content of that taxonomy term. So the link would be something as "/the-register/countach-gallardo-lp550-2-valentino-balboni".
But when i test this with a contextual filter "Term ID" with " Provide default value" and "Fixed" with a value of "1" the preview works but not the page it self?

Comment: If you set your contextual filter to grab the % part and use that as an ID. Well because `countach-gallardo-lp550-2-valentino-balboni` is not a term id... term id's need to be numeric. Needs to be `/the-register/1`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I explane it in more detail.

Comment: I want to keep the full taxonomy name in the url like "/the-register/countach-gallardo-lp550-2-valentino-balboni".

Comment: In the view i have had at first a contextual filter "Taxonomy term by name" with "Provide default value" "Raw value from URL" "Path component" "2", and the "Use path alias" enabeld, and by "Case" en "Case in path" "No transform" and under "MORE" the "Transform spaces to dashes in URL". This goes very well, with taxonomy term with no dashes, like "Countach Gallardo LP550 2 Valentino Balboni" but it won't work with taxonomy term name with a dash like "Countach Gallardo LP550-2 Valentino Balboni" (between LP550 and 2)

Comment: So i thought i write a custom module with a custom default argument, that takes the url and return the taxonomy id. But now i try to test it with a default return of "1" (taxonomy term id 1), but this works in the preview but not on the page it self